# CUDA on Debian 9 - Where is the toolkit?

Tags: nvidia

I already followed some tutorial in how to install CUDA in Debian 9.

The best one so far, that let me use `nvcc` was the one you can found in [this link](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers).

Now the thing is, I cannot find the toolkit. I already tried to use `find` command, etc, but nothing. Has anyone any idea where the toolkit is?

Because, whenever I run `nvcc` to compile a simple "Hello World" program using CUDA, it gives erros because it cannot find the libraries. And when I try to install the samples, it asks for the toolkit path, and I cannot find it.

**ADDED:**

I installed everything using:

```
apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit  nvidia-driver
```

After this, I ran:

```
nvcc -V
```

To check if nvcc was installed, the output was this:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016
```

The I download the .run file for ubuntu 16.04, and CUDA 8.0:

cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux-run

I the skip the installation of drivers, and the toolkit installation, and jump right to Samples Installation

```
Do you accept the previously read EULA?
accept/decline/quit: accept

You are attempting to install on an unsupported configuration. Do you wish to continue?
(y)es/(n)o [ default is no ]: y

Install NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 375.26?
(y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: n

Install the CUDA 8.0 Toolkit?
(y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: n

Install the CUDA 8.0 Samples?
(y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: y

Enter CUDA Samples Location
 [ default is /root ]: /home/sergiobranco/cuda_samples

Enter Toolkit Location
 [ default is /usr/local/cuda-8.0 ]: 

Error: cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-8.0
Enter Toolkit Location
 [ default is /usr/local/cuda-8.0 ]: ??????????
```

The problem is that it asks for the toolkit location and I do not know it. I press enter and then I try to install the samples but this is the error:

```
Error: unsupported compiler: 6.3.0. Use --override to override this check.
Missing recommended library: libXmu.so

Error: cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-8.0

===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Not Selected
Toolkit:  Installation Failed. Using unsupported Compiler.
Samples:  Cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-8.0


Logfile is /tmp/cuda_install_3212.log
```

I already used the --override argument, but it fails to.

After this I tried to at least compile one of the "first programs" given by cuda:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__
void saxpy(int n, float a, float *x, float *y)
{
  int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < n) y[i] = a*x[i] + y[i];
}

int main(void)
{
  int N = 1<<20;
  float *x, *y, *d_x, *d_y;
  x = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
  y = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

  cudaMalloc(&d_x, N*sizeof(float)); 
  cudaMalloc(&d_y, N*sizeof(float));

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = 1.0f;
    y[i] = 2.0f;
  }

  cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_y, y, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // Perform SAXPY on 1M elements
  saxpy<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, 2.0f, d_x, d_y);

  cudaMemcpy(y, d_y, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  float maxError = 0.0f;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    maxError = max(maxError, abs(y[i]-4.0f));
  printf("Max error: %f\n", maxError);

  cudaFree(d_x);
  cudaFree(d_y);
  free(x);
  free(y);
}
```

But this is the output:

```
nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8 hello.c 
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
hello.c:3:1: error: unknown type name '__global__'
__global__
^
hello.c:4:1: error: expected identifier or '('
void saxpy(int n, float a, float *x, float *y)
^
hello.c:14:15: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  x = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
              ^
hello.c:14:15: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'malloc'
hello.c:17:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cudaMalloc' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  cudaMalloc(&d_x, N*sizeof(float)); 
  ^
hello.c:25:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cudaMemcpy' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  ^
hello.c:25:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cudaMemcpyHostToDevice'
  cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                                      ^
hello.c:26:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cudaMemcpyHostToDevice'
  cudaMemcpy(d_y, y, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                                      ^
hello.c:29:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'saxpy'
  saxpy<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, 2.0f, d_x, d_y);
  ^
hello.c:29:10: error: expected expression
  saxpy<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, 2.0f, d_x, d_y);
         ^
hello.c:29:29: error: expected expression
  saxpy<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, 2.0f, d_x, d_y);
                            ^
hello.c:29:31: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  saxpy<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, 2.0f, d_x, d_y);
                              ^
hello.c:29:34: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  saxpy<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, 2.0f, d_x, d_y);
                                 ^~~~
hello.c:29:40: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  saxpy<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, 2.0f, d_x, d_y);
                                       ^~~
hello.c:31:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost'
  cudaMemcpy(y, d_y, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
                                      ^
hello.c:35:16: warning: implicit declaration of function 'max' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    maxError = max(maxError, abs(y[i]-4.0f));
               ^
hello.c:35:30: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'abs' with type 'int (int)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    maxError = max(maxError, abs(y[i]-4.0f));
                             ^
hello.c:35:30: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'abs'
hello.c:35:30: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
    maxError = max(maxError, abs(y[i]-4.0f));
                             ^
hello.c:35:30: note: use function 'fabsf' instead
    maxError = max(maxError, abs(y[i]-4.0f));
                             ^~~
                             fabsf
hello.c:35:30: note: include the header <math.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'fabsf'
hello.c:38:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cudaFree' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  cudaFree(d_x);
  ^
hello.c:40:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'free' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  free(x);
  ^
11 warnings and 8 errors generated.
```

Comment: The site you have posted states *...The Debian CUDA packages unfortunately do not include the Toolkit samples. To install these yourself you need to download the "Ubuntu 16.04" .run install file for Cuda 8 from...*

Comment: Yes, the problem is to install the samples you have to provide the toolkit path...

Comment: It might be good if you add more details to your question and outline the steps you already done. Installed the tookit from the Nvidia site?

Comment: Added a lot more information... Hope it is enough to explain what I have done

Comment: When you run the `cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux-run` file and it prompts`Enter Toolkit Location
 [ default is /usr/local/cuda-8.0 ]:`, it is asking where you want to install the toolkit, not where it is installed.

Comment: Sorry, I had posted the wrong output.... I already edited to the correct one, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally I was able to install everything and is working correctly. I will post here a full tutorial on how I did it for debian 9:

1st Step:

```
apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit  nvidia-driver
```

Was to run the command above, you should check [this link](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers) in order to get a better overview in how to do it correctly for you board.

This been said, then I download the following run file [CUDA 8.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/Prod2/local_installers/cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux-run)

I also had to install these:

```
apt-get install libglu1-mesa libxi-dev libxmu-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Then I had to include the toolkit to my $PATH in order to make it work:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Then you must do this:

```
sh /home/username/Downloads/cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run --tar mxvf
cp InstallUtils.pm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base/
export $PERL5LIB
```

And now you can install the samples:

```
sh /home/username/Downloads/cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run
```

When it asks for the toolkit path you should put:

```
/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

This were my answers:

```
Do you accept the previously read EULA?
accept/decline/quit: accept

You are attempting to install on an unsupported configuration. Do you wish to continue?
(y)es/(n)o [ default is no ]: y

Install NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 375.26?
(y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: n

Install the CUDA 8.0 Toolkit?
(y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: n

Install the CUDA 8.0 Samples?
(y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: y

Enter CUDA Samples Location
 [ default is /root ]: /somewher

Enter Toolkit Location
 [ default is /usr/local/cuda-8.0 ]: /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

It now should install the samples without any trouble. Then you can go to the folder inside where you install them and run:

```
nvcc -ccbin clang++-3.8 somefile.cu -o somename
```

And there you go . . .

If you want to install pycuda you have only to do this:

```
apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools libboost-python-dev libboost-thread-dev -y
apt-get install python-pycuda
```